# Android Map issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to calculate if some pins I have are inside my screen. I have this function and I am always getting false as a return. Any ideas:

```
public static boolean isInMap(final GeoPoint topLeftGeo, final GeoPoint bottmRightGeo, final GeoPoint point)
{
  Log.d(TAG, ""+topLeftGeo.toString());
  Log.d(TAG, ""+point.toString());
  Log.d(TAG, ""+bottmRightGeo.toString());
  
  boolean isIn = false;
  
  if( (point.getLatitudeE6() >= topLeftGeo.getLatitudeE6() 
      && point.getLatitudeE6() <= bottmRightGeo.getLatitudeE6()) 
      && (point.getLongitudeE6() >= topLeftGeo.getLongitudeE6() 
      && point.getLongitudeE6() <= bottmRightGeo.getLongitudeE6()))
  {
    isIn = true;
  }

  return isIn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the logic for the latitudes the wrong way round. The top left latitude is greater than the bottom right. Your point latitude must be <= top latitude and >= bottom latitude.

Comment: i think you might be totally correct. please let me check this right away.

Answer (score 0):

First, just a note: you can simplify your code just a bit:

```
     public static boolean isInMap(final GeoPoint topLeftGeo,
     final GeoPoint bottmRightGeo, final GeoPoint point) {
          Log.d(TAG, ""+topLeftGeo.toString());
          Log.d(TAG, ""+point.toString());
          Log.d(TAG, ""+bottmRightGeo.toString());     

          if((point.getLatitudeE6() >= topLeftGeo.getLatitudeE6() && 
point.getLatitudeE6() <=   bottmRightGeo.getLatitudeE6()) 
&&    (point.getLongitudeE6() >= topLeftGeo.getLongitudeE6() && point.getLongitudeE6() <=             bottmRightGeo.getLongitudeE6()))
          {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
      }
```

As far as why it's always returning false, well it's very hard to tell from the limited information you've provided, but I recommend a divide and conquer approach. You have four conditions in your `if statement` that need to be satisfied in order for your method to ever return true. Try logging each condition, like this:

```
Log.v("latE6 greater than topLeftGeo", String.valueOf((point.getLatitudeE6() >= topLeftGeo.getLatitudeE6()));
```

And see which one is showing up false, then go from there.

Comment: actually i have already done the if condition brake and still getting the false as return. I also have the correct numbers(points) i am testing. This is weird...